# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) on release

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an flutter app with Firebase auth. When I'm testing with flutter run at my android emulator or my android phone the app runs pretty well without major errors.

The problem happens when I try to build an apk or an appbundle and Firebase.initializeApp() fail.

Since I'm not running in debug mode I'm not sure how to trace this error.

[UPDATE]

I could trace the error catching the exception thrown from Firebase.initializeApp() and was **MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)**

I still couldn't figured out why this error just appears on release while on debug runs perfectly.

Here is my app/build.gradle snippet

```
(...)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

(...)

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

And my project build.gradle dependecies

```
(...)

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.9, 0.99.99]'
}

(...)
```

And my firebase dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue so what I did was in my `main.dart` file I just added this code and it worked out for me. What it does is if `Firebase.intitalizeApp()` fails then it will show an errorPage which i have created and if it loads then it can show the application home page and if it is still loading then it shows a loading page. Here is the code for it. Hope it helps you worked for me.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Show Application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<Help4YouUser>.value(
            value: AuthService().user,
            child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Initialization
        return PouringHourGlassPageLoad();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply but I think your solution just handles the error showing an error page, after that how can you overpass this splash page? I think the problem persists in the connection with firebase

Comment: @LeonardoUgiete You can add a refresh button in the error page where it will restart the app if clicked and it will retry to initialize firebase. That might work